# firefox <a href="foo.php#id"> always goes to top of page

Tags: url, firefox, href

Alright, I have a site [www.obliqueideas.com](http://obliqueideas.com).  In FF, when I click on one of the portfolio circles, it always goes to the top of the portfolio page.  If I refresh the portfolio page, it then goes to the correct href location.  Anyhow, the problem doesn't exist in any other browser I have tested.  Let me know your thoughts.

I updated the code – removed an unnecessary < div >, and changed the tag structure to match the bio section, but the problem persists.  I'm still testing this locally, so it's not reflected in the site.  Here's the updated code.

```
<div id="item2" class="item">
     <h2>Some title</h2>
     <img src="/" />
     <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

I really don't understand why the bio section of the site would work in FF and the portfolio section wouldn't.

UPDATE:  I wondered whether or not the class item could be confusing FF, so I changed the class name, and it worked.  Here's my final code...really simple, but hey, it worked, right?

```
     <div id="item8" class="content">
          <a name="item8"></a>
          <h2>Some Title</h2>
          <img src="/" />
          <p> some text</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wondered whether or not the class item could be confusing FF, so I changed the class name, and it worked. Here's my final code...really simple, but hey, it worked, right?

```
 <div id="item8" class="content">
      <a name="item8"></a>
      <h2>Some Title</h2>
      <img src="/" />
      <p> some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate IDs:

```
<div class="item" id="item3">
        <a id="item3"></a>
```

The ID attribute [must be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). The duplicate IDs is confusing Firefox as to which element it should scroll to, so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: so which one would you remove? the <div> id or the <a> id?

Comment: @Daniel You don't have to remove either of them, just change the ID of one of them.